# bettercap not working on kali linux

Tags: kali-linux, arm

I've been attempting to perform an SSL strip MITM attack with my Rasberry pi 4B 4GB running kali Linux. after loading all the required modules in better cap and navigating to a website without HSTS on my target machine I'm not seeing the traffic show up much less the login credentials.
Commands I'm entering:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward ...
bettercap -iface wlan0 ...
set https.proxy.sslstrip true ...
https.proxy on ...
set arp.spoof.targets (Target IP) ...
arp.spoof on ...
net.sniff on ...
```

I should also mention that bettercap is frequently and continuously detecting and then losing new endpoints. I've tried navigating to the website on my target machine while it's detected the right endpoint and before it loses it to no avail. I've been able to use arpspoof and urlsnarf to successfully monitor HTTP traffic before in my MITM attack without SSL strip.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also losing endpoints and creating new ones all the time with the built-in wifi card on the raspberry pi 4.

using it on my own wifi where the router is less than 1 meter away

can't be anything with signal strength.

Using the broadband cable trying to spoof my pc there are no end point errors, but the mac address does not change on my windows pc running `arp -a` in command prompt.

Not sure if it works. But I can see a lot of connections on my main pc: google api's and so on, but can't see the unencrypted data when I visit unencrypted http pages asthe udemy course says I should be able to.